# Will a monitor connected to a usb-hub show image from Android?

Tags: usb, external-display

I'd like to connect a VGA monitor to an Android device. I'm thinking to connect a usb-hub to the device, then plug USB to VGA adapter into the hub. Also a mouse and a keyboard are going to be connected to that hub (i.e. to the Android device). Is it going to work or display should be the only thing to be connected to micro-usb port of the Android device?
I.e. this way:

```
Android device -> usb hub -> usb to vga adapter -> display, 
                          -> keyboard, 
                          -> mouse.
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but you posted the same question on both [su] and [Android.SE]. The one on Android Enthusiasts is on-topic. On the other hand, Super User generally doesn't accept questions about mobile devices, thus it's off-topic and rightly closed, but the mod decided to migrate it to Android Enthusiasts as goodwill. However, this made the 2 same questions exist on this site instead. Thus, I have to close either one as self-duplicate. Please continue the activity in the original question instead. Thanks.